# VHDL - retrieving wrong data from array of records

Tags: arrays, vhdl, record, fpga, quartus

I am trying to retrieve data from an array of records constant. This is what i have in my current implementation:

```
CONSTANT Total_Feeds : INTEGER := 12;

TYPE Feed IS RECORD
        s_Divisor       : INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 255;
        Display_Text    : STRING(1 TO 8);
    END RECORD Feed;

TYPE Feed_Array IS ARRAY (0 TO Total_Feeds -1) OF Feed;

CONSTANT FEED_INFO : Feed_Array := (
        (225,"""0.02mm"""),
        (112,"""0.04mm"""),
        (75,"""0.06mm"""),
        (56,"""0.08mm"""),
        (45,"""0.10mm"""),
        (38,"""0.12mm"""),
        (32,"""0.14mm"""),
        (28,"""0.16mm"""),
        (25,"""0.18mm"""),
        (23,"""0.20mm"""),
        (20,"""0.22mm"""),
        (19,"""0.24mm""")
    );

------lower section of menu fsm----------
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if (reset = '1') then
            menu_pr <= start;
            feed_index_pr <= 2;
            ks_divisor_pr <= 0;
        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
            menu_pr <= menu_nx;
            feed_index_pr <= feed_index_nx;
            ks_divisor_pr <= ks_divisor_nx;
        end if;     
    end process;

------upper section of menu fsm----------
    process (menu_pr, menu_on_flag, delayed_select, delayed_up, 
                delayed_down, delayed_left, feed_index_pr, thread_index_pr, 
                delayed_right, menu_left_flag, menu_right_flag, menu_up_flag, menu_down_flag)
    variable feedindex : integer range 0 to total_feeds;
    begin       
        case menu_pr is
            when start =>
                feedindex := feed_index_pr;

                feed_index_nx <= feedindex;
                ks_divisor_nx <= FEED_INFO(feedindex).s_Divisor;
                menu_nx <= feed_left;
            when feed_left =>       
                feedindex := feed_index_pr;

                feed_index_nx <= feedindex;
                ks_divisor_nx <= FEED_INFO(feedindex).s_Divisor;


                if (menu_on_flag = '1' and delayed_right = '1' and menu_right_flag = '1') then
                    menu_nx <= feed_left_right;
                else
                    menu_nx <= feed_left;
                end if; 
             when feed_left_right =>
                feedindex := feed_index_pr + 1;
                if (feedindex > (Total_Feeds - 1)) then
                    feedindex := 0;
                    feed_index_nx <= feedindex;
                    ks_divisor_nx <= FEED_INFO(feedindex).s_Divisor;
                    menu_nx <= feed_left;
                else
                    feed_index_nx <= feedindex;
                    ks_divisor_nx <= FEED_INFO(feedindex).s_Divisor;
                    menu_nx <= feed_left;
                end if; 
             end case;
    end process;
rate_out <=ks_divisor_pr;
```

States are added after successful verification with simulation.

I'm trying to get the s_divisor for each record from a process using the following command:

`ks_divisor_nx <= FEED_INFO(feedindex).s_Divisor;`
Where `feedindex` changes from `0 to Total_Feeds -1`, and ks_divisor is `integer range 0 to 255`.

Simulation results show correct output for all assignments except for the records with index 0, 1, and 2. Simulation output shows values: 11, 48, and 33 respectively.

[simulation results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlivK.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show that code that reproduces the error

Comment: Show the code for the process you are using

Comment: Your problem [doesn't appear to be caused by any of the snippets you have provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YZ9K.jpg).

Comment: Following your advises helped me find the problem while making a minimal example to reproduce the issue. In my entity declaration i had `rate_out` ranging from 0 to Total_Feeds instead of 255. Results are as expected now. Thank you for your responses all of you.